# Modal does not hide FullCalendar elements

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar in React and need a modal to pop-up when a button is clicked.

The issue I'm experiencing is that certain elements of the calendar do not fade behind the overlay and are instead at full opacity and in front of the modal.

Specifically, in `dayGridMonth` view the elements are the internal grid that makes up the calendar, the date numbers in each cell, the events and the current day highlight (i.e. all [internal calendar elements](https://prnt.sc/1q22mk8)). However, the toolbar header, the day text and the external border are all hidden as desired.

When in `listDay` or `listWeek` views, only the active button in the toolbar is misbehaving.

I've tried implementing a plain JS modal and also using `react-modal`. The issue persists in both.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import TaskModal from './TaskModal';

function Calendar (props) {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  function addEvent () {
    setModalOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <FullCalendar
        headerToolbar={{
          start: "addEvent",
          center: "foo",
          end: "bar",
        }}
        customButtons={{
          addEvent: {
            text: "+",
            click: addEvent,
          }
        }}
        some other props...
      >
      <TaskModal modalOpen={modalOpen} setModalOpen={setModalOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import Modal from "react-modal";


export default function TaskModal (props) {
  Modal.setAppElement("#root");

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={props.taskModalVisible}
      onRequestClose={false}
      contentLabel="My dialog"
    >
      <div>My modal dialog.</div>
      <button onClick={() => props.setTaskModalVisible(false)}>Close modal</button>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply that the problematic elements had a very high CSS `z-index` (as high as 999). This was resolved by adding `className` and `overlayClassName` props to the `Modal`. Then giving these classes an even higher `z-index` so that everything else would be behind.